# How can I evaluate a block in the LLVM debugger, with xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, block, llvm

I have a block called `myBlock`.

I put a breakpoint after the creation of  `myBlock`. In the console, I type

```
  p myBlock(@"5")
```

All I get is the error

```
 error: called object type '__block_literal_generic *' is not a function or function pointer
 error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

**So, it it possible to evaluate in block in the debugger console?**

PS:
More code

```
NSArray * array = @[@"a", @"b"] ;

BOOL (^myBlock)(NSString *) = ^BOOL(NSString * string)
    {
        return [string isEqualToString:@"hello"] ;
    } ;

// The breakpoint is here

for (NSString * str in array)
{
    myBlock(str) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to explicitely cast the variable to the block type:

```
(lldb) p ( (BOOL(^)(NSString *)) myBlock )(@"hello")
(BOOL) $3 = YES
(lldb) p ( (BOOL(^)(NSString *)) myBlock )(@"world")
(BOOL) $4 = NO
```